# How to loop SELECT SUM of daily MAX and MIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables that I'm trying to select, unit and feed.

Table `unit` is a metadata table that contains

```
unitid, userid, guid, fields, createdat
```

and the other table, `feed`, contains

```
feedid, unitid, value, createdat
```

Sample data for table unit:

```
1,1000,'0b243396-a015-11e6-8001-9cf387d90940','a','2016-11-04 21:36:32.71281'
2,1000,'0b243396-a015-11e6-8001-9cf387d90941','b','2016-11-04 21:40:32.71281'
3,1001,'0b243396-a015-11e6-8001-9cf387d90942','b','2016-11-04 21:47:32.71281'
4,1001,'0b243396-a015-11e6-8001-9cf387d90943','c','2016-11-04 21:50:32.71281'
```

and table feed:

```
1,1,'0.0021','2016-11-05 00:50:32.71281'
2,1,'0.0025','2016-11-05 01:00:32.71281'
3,2,'0.0008','2016-11-05 00:51:22.71281'
4,2,'0.0018','2016-11-05 01:01:22.71281'
...
24,1,'0.0800','2016-11-05 23:55:32.71281'
25,2,'0.0540','2016-11-05 23:55:32.71281'
```

What I'm trying to get is select total of MIN and MAX of every unit registered by userid = n.

I already tried this:

```
SELECT SUM(value::DOUBLE PRECISION)::text FROM 
((SELECT f.value FROM feed f, unit u WHERE f.unitid = unit.id AND f.createdat >= now()::date + interval '1h' ORDER BY f.createdat DESC LIMIT 1) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT f.value FROM feed f, unit u WHERE f.unitid = unit.id AND f.createdat >= now()::date + interval '1h' ORDER BY f.createdat ASC LIMIT 1)) t
```

But I'm not sure where I should put the userid = n clause.

So how can I select total of MIN and MAX of every units registered by spesific userid? (daily interval)

Comment: Given your sample data: What's the result you would expect to get?

Comment: Just total for unit #1 plus unit #2 (registered by userid 1000), that is 0.1369 (unit #1 0.0821 (0.0021+0.0800) + unit #2 0.0548 (0.0008+0.0540))

Comment: By "summary", do you mean "sum"? Ie do you want `min(value) + mav(value)`?

Comment: yeah, sorry I should use the word total not summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT f.unitid,
       min(f.value) + max(f.value)
FROM unit u
   JOIN feed f ON u.id = f.unitid
WHERE u.userid = 1000
GROUP BY f.unitid;

┌────────┬──────────┐
│ unitid │ ?column? │
├────────┼──────────┤
│      1 │   0.0821 │
│      2 │   0.0548 │
└────────┴──────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I'm getting 42703 error
(column "unitid" specified in USING clause does not exist in left table)

Comment: Well, I was unsure if the column in `unit` was really called `id` or `unitid`, since you use both in your question. I have changed the answer so that it assumes that the column is called `id`.

Comment: And how do I total that so that it only outputs 0.1369? (from 0.0821+0.0548)

Comment: Okay got it. I end up to something like this:



`SELECT SUM(total) FROM (SELECT MIN(f.value::DOUBLE PRECISION) + MAX(f.value::DOUBLE PRECISION) AS total FROM unit u JOIN feed f ON u.id = f.unitid AND f.createdat >= now()::date + interval '1h' WHERE u.userid = 1000 GROUP BY f.unitid) t`

Comment: Exactly right, just surround it with an outer query.

Comment: If I may ask one more question, is this the optimal query?
Btw, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Don't know, it will probably perform a sequential scan on both tables. if there are lots and lots of `feed`s per `unit`, you might be better off with an index on `(unitid, value)` and something that looks more like your original query. My query was just the simplest way to write it.